# Apache spark rest API

Tags: curl, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I'm using the spark-submit command I have for the log4j properties to invoke a Spark-submit like this:

```
/opt/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit \
--driver-java-options \
"-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/test_api/log4j-driver.properties\ --class Test testing.jar
```

How do I do `--driver-java-options`, to submit a job via curl (Apache Spark's Hidden REST API)?

I tried this:

```
curl -X POST http://host-ip:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "" ],
"appResource" : "hdfs://host-ip:9000/test/testing.jar",
"clientSparkVersion" : "1.6.2",
"environmentVariables" : {
"SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
"mainClass" : "Test",
"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions" : "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/test_api/log4j-driver.properties",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.jars" : "hdfs://host-ip:9000/test/testing.jar",
"spark.app.name" : "Test",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
"spark.eventLog.dir": "hdfs://host-ip:9000/test/spark-events",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "spark://host-ip:7077"
}
}'
```

Job submitted successfully and response was given, but with one uknownField:

```
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20160810210057-0091",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "1.6.2",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20160810210057-0091",
  "success" : true,
  "unknownFields" : [ "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions" ]
}
```

`"unknownFields" : [ "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions" ]`

I have also tried `driverExtraJavaOptions` as follows:

```
curl -X POST http://host-ip:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "" ],
"appResource" : "hdfs://host-ip:9000/test/testing.jar",
"clientSparkVersion" : "1.6.2",
"environmentVariables" : {
"SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
"mainClass" : "Test",
"driverExtraJavaOptions" : "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/test_api/log4j-driver.properties",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.jars" : "hdfs://host-ip:9000/test/testing.jar",
"spark.app.name" : "Test",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
"spark.eventLog.dir": "hdfs://host-ip:9000/test/spark-events",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "spark://host-ip:7077"
}
}'
```

But got a similar response:

```
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20160810211432-0094",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "1.6.2",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20160810211432-0094",
  "success" : true,
  "unknownFields" : [ "driverExtraJavaOptions" ]
}
```

Why is this?
I looked at [spark-submit.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala) and referenced the [Spark  REST API](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1o_z-3bfOAhWI4SYKHTx9BZIQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Farturmkrtchyan.com%2Fapache-spark-hidden-rest-api&usg=AFQjCNEPh-5gWfrqJ9kGqNHymsqaLWCnQQ&sig2=nokuaJ1VAH7DfJYNkp3kyA&bvm=bv.129389765,d.eWE)

Comment: Are are on standalone cluster ? I wanted to use Spark Rest but it seems that Spark Rest don't work on YARN.

Comment: Yes, I am in Standalone mode, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**It works now putting  Dlog4j.configuration=file:/// (/// path for local file) and putting spark.driver.extraJavaOptions inside sparkProperties**

```
curl -X POST http://host-ip:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "" ],
"appResource" : "hdfs://host-ip:9000/test/testing.jar",
"clientSparkVersion" : "1.6.2",
"environmentVariables" : {
"SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
"mainClass" : "Test",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.jars" : "hdfs://host-ip:9000/test/testing.jar",
"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions" : "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/log4j-driver.properties",
"spark.app.name" : "Test",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
"spark.eventLog.dir": "hdfs://host-ip:9000/test/spark-events",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "client",
"spark.master" : "spark://host-ip:7077"
}
}'
```